# Know first match of COUNTIFS in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, count

I have a formula that counts rows with two conditions.

```
=COUNTIFS(CITY!A2:A3000;"<>";CITY!D2:D3000;"")
```

Now, my purpose is to know the first cell that matches the conditions (i.e. A2,A25,A56,etc...).

I.e:

```
    Date (A)   | Location (B) | Teacher (C)
    =======================================
    16/12/2020 | Spain        | Luis 
--> 17/12/2020 |              |      
    17/12/2020 | Spain        | Luis
```

Cursor goes to B2 because Date file is not empty and Location is empty

Can you help me?

Comment: The formula that you are showing may not do what you think it does. As it is right now, this formula counts how many cells are not empty in the range `A2:A3000`. What is it supposed to do? Could you explain in which context you are using this? I feel that you'd like to get the first row in which columns A and B are different. Is this right?

Comment: My formula counts rows where column A has some text and column D is empty. It works fine.


Starting from that formula, can I know which is the first row?

Another way of posing my question is: How do I know the first row with two conditions at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(HYPERLINK("#gid=0&range=A"&MIN(IF((B2:B="")*(C2:C=""), ROW(A2:A), )), "jump"))
```

[image]

Comment: I've copied that formula changing gid number for my own gid number. It shows an error.

Comment: @monicapo try: `=INDEX(HYPERLINK("#gid=0&range=A"&MIN(IF((B2:B="")*(C2:C=""); ROW(A2:A); )); "jump"))`

Comment: It works! But I chnaged B2:B="" to B2:B<>"" for first condition